# Trying to upload an image. But I get errors

Tags: php

I am trying to upload an image but I am getting errors. Here is my code so far

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost"; 
    $username = "root"; 
    $password = "";  
    $dbname = ""; //Taken out for stackoverflow question

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $dir = "ads/";
    $file = $dir . basename($_FILES['cf']['name']);
    $uploadSuccess = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (!$conn)
    {
        echo 'Could not connect';
    }
    else 
    {
        if (!empty($_FILES['cf'] && $_POST['category']))
        {
            $filesize = getimagesize($_FILES['cf']['tmp_name']);
            if ($filesize != false)
            {
                if (file_exists($file))
                {
                    echo 'File already exists';
                    $uploadSuccess = 0;
                }
                if ($_FILES['cf']['size'] > 500000)
                {
                    echo 'Cannot use that large of a file';
                    $uploadSuccess = 0;
                }
                if ($imageFileType != 'jpg' && $imageFileType != 'png' && $imageFileType != 'jpeg')
                {
                    echo 'Only jpg, png, and jpeg files are allowed';
                    $uploadSuccess = 0;
                }
                if ($uploadSuccess == 0)
                {
                    echo 'Sorry, your file was not uploaded';
                }
                else
                {
                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cf']['tmp_name'], $file))
                    {
                        echo 'The file: '.basename($_FILES['cf']['name'])." has been uploaded";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        echo 'Sorry, there was an error uploading your file';
                    }
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                $uploadSuccess = 0;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

That code isn't working. I have been on this for two days. First trying to get it into a database. Now a directory. Here is the errors localhost gave me.

[image: Errors given by localhost]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to check
if folder exist

**php code:**

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = ""; //Taken out for stackoverflow question

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $rootPath = dirname(__FILE__);
    $dir = $rootPath. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."ads";


    $file = 'ads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .basename($_FILES['cf']['name']);
    $fileNewName = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'].'_'.rand(1,9999) .'_'. basename($_FILES['cf']['name']);
    $uploadSuccess = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (!$conn)
    {
        echo 'Could not connect';
    }
    else
    {
        if (!empty($_FILES['cf'] && $_POST['category']))
        {
            $filesize = getimagesize($_FILES['cf']['tmp_name']);
            if ($filesize != false)
            {
                if (file_exists($fileNewName))
                {
                    echo 'File already exists';
                    $uploadSuccess = 0;
                }
                if ($_FILES['cf']['size'] > 500000)
                {
                    echo 'Cannot use that large of a file';
                    $uploadSuccess = 0;
                }
                if ($imageFileType != 'jpg' && $imageFileType != 'png' && $imageFileType != 'jpeg')
                {
                    echo 'Only jpg, png, and jpeg files are allowed';
                    $uploadSuccess = 0;
                }
                if ($uploadSuccess == 0)
                {
                    echo 'Sorry, your file was not uploaded';
                }
                else
                {

                    if (!is_dir($dir)){

                        if (!mkdir($dir, 0777, true)) {
                            die('Sorry, failed to create folder'.$dir );
                        }
                    }

                    if (!is_writable($dir)) {
                        die( 'folder is not writeble'.dir);
                    }


                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cf']['tmp_name'], $fileNewName))
                    {
                        echo 'The file: '.basename($_FILES['cf']['name'])." has been uploaded";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'Sorry, there was an error uploading your file';
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $uploadSuccess = 0;
            }
        }
    }

exit;
?>
```

Comment: Image was uploaded.

Comment: Now how do I change the name it is likely that some people will name their ad the same exact thing. So how can I enter it with a different name than the original uploaded one?

Comment: Yes, it is uploading. But the name is the issue now.

Comment: **add  code:**    $file = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5(rand(1,99999) . basename($_FILES['cf']['name'])); So every uploaded file  will have new name. Is it ok for you?

Comment: Where do I add it?

Comment: Even though I am adding a png file it gives the error Only png, jpeg, and jpg files can be uploaded

Comment: Only jpg, png, and jpeg files are allowedSorry, your file was not uploaded

Comment: That is given. But I am using a png file.

Comment: @J.Doedoedoedoe, you're branching your question, different inquiry different question also.

Comment: I am giving the error. Besides, this is the last question and I need to get this done. The only thing wrong is it gives me an error can only use certain extensions. But I upload png and png is supported. So why is it giving me that error?

Comment: Now, I get files, but not image file. In fact no extension at all.

Comment: I +1'ed this in both my accounts. And accepted this answer. You have done a great job and I appreciate it. However one more thing with this code the extension is not added. How would I add it?

Comment: extension added to filename

Answer (score 0):

You should check that 'ads/' directory exists and your web server user has write permissions on it.

Comment: It is existing. And as for writing permissions... it was Read only. I changed that but it is still not working. Giving the same errors.

Comment: It keeps resetting back to Read only