# php undefined index with multiple file upload

Tags: php, html, image-uploading, forms

I have this code but I can't get what's wrong with it. Any help will be appreciated. Please don't be too quick to mark it as a duplicate without giving me a solution as I have been through all question that are similar and they do not answer my problem as I have already checked if file is uploaded be for processing it and still get this error UNDEFINED INDEX:

**Html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <form  role="form" method="post" action="test2.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <label class="control-label">Call Sign</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="call_sign" />
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label">Picture</label>
                <img src="Koala.jpg" alt="with responsive image feature" class="img-responsive img-circle">


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <label class="control-label">Driver First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_Name" />
            </div> 
        </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <label class="control-label">Driver Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_Name" />
            </div>
         </div>
   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
              <label for = "fileToUpload">File input</label>

              <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" >
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-8">
              <label class="control-label">Location</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Location" />
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-4 selectContainer">
          <label class="control-label">Company Shirt</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="CShirt">
                    <option value="">Choose </option>
                    <option value="Good">Good</option>
                    <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
                    <option value="UniformNotWorn">Uniform Not Worn</option>
                    <option value="Untidy">Untidy</option>
          </select>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-4 selectContainer">
       <label class="control-label">Trousers</label>
       <select class="form-control" name="Trousers">
                    <option value="">Choose </option>
                    <option value="Clean/Smart">Clean/Smart</option>
                    <option value="Acceptable">Acceptable</option>
                    <option value="Jeans/Casual">Jeans/ Casual</option>
                    <option value="Untidy">Untidy</option>
       </select>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-4 selectContainer">
       <label class="control-label">General Appearance</label>
          <select class="form-control"  name="Appearance">
                    <option value="">Choose </option>
                    <option value="Good">Good</option>
                    <option value="Fair">Fair</option>
                    <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
          </select>
   </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="row">
      <label class="control-label">In the Vehicle</label>
         <div class = "checkbox">
           <label><input type = "checkbox" value="Tea/Coffe" name="In_the_Vehicle"> Tea/Coffe</label>
         </div>
         <div class = "checkbox">
            <label><input type = "checkbox" value="Eating" name="In_the_Vehicle"> Eating</label>
         </div>
         <div class = "checkbox">
            <label><input type = "checkbox" value="Smoking" name="In_the_Vehicle"> Smoking</label>
         </div>
   </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Assessor Comments</label>
    <div>
       <textarea class="controlline" name="Assessor_Comments" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>   
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Driver Comments</label>
    <div>
       <textarea class="controlline" name="Driver_Comments" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Kit Required</label>
    <div>
       <label class="radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="Kit_Required" value="DMN Shirts" /> DMN Shirts
       </label>
       <label class="radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="Kit_Required" value="DMN Jacket" /> DMN Jacket
       </label>
       <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Kit_Required" value="BMW Jacket" /> BMW Jacket
       </label>
       <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Kit_Required" value="Hi-Viz-Jacket" />Hi-Viz-Jacket
       </label>
       <label class="radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="Kit_Required" value="ID Badge" /> ID Badge
       </label>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
                   <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" name="Kit_Required" value="Tyre_Guage" /> Tyre Guage
                   </label>
                   <label class="radio-inline">
                     <input type="radio" name="Kit_Required" value="Trade_Plate_Bands" /> Trade Plate Bands
                   </label>
                   <label class="radio-inline">
                     <input type="radio" name="Kit_Required" value="MiVIS_Ruler/Kit" /> MiVIS Ruler/Kit
                   </label>
                </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Training Wanted</label>
     <div>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="Training_Wanted" value="Yes" /> Yes
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
           <input type="radio" name="Training_Wanted" value="No" /> No
        </label>
     </div>
</div>


    <button type="submit" class="button" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**php code:**

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $query    = "INSERT INTO spot_checkdetails(location,CShirt,trouser,appearance,kitReq,Training,fk1_callSIgn)
    VALUES('$_POST[Location]','$_POST[CShirt]' ,'$_POST[Trousers]' ,'$_POST[Appearance]','$_POST[Kit_Required]' ,'$_POST[Training_Wanted]','$_POST[call_sign]')";
        $result   = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if (!$result) die("database acess failed".$connection->error);
        $foreignk = "select id from spot_checkdetails order by id desc limit 1";
        $result   = mysqli_query($connection, $foreignk);

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $reqry = $row["id"];
        }

        $query  = "INSERT INTO spotcheckcomment(assCom,driCom,spot_checkdetails_id)VALUES('$_POST[Assessor_Comments]','$_POST[Driver_Comments]','".$reqry."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        $foreign2 = "select id from spotcheckcomment order by id desc limit 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $foreign2);

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $reqry2 = $row["id"];
        }
        $foreign3 = "select fk1_callSIgn from spot_checkdetails order by id desc limit 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $foreign3);

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $reqry3 = $row["fk1_callSIgn"];
        }
        if (!empty($_POST)) {  // **check weather the form is submitted or not**
            // Where the file is going to be placed 
            $target_path  = "uploads/";
            $random_digit = rand(0000, 9999)."_";
            $jobnumber    = $reqry3."_".$random_digit;


            //combine random digit to you file name to create new file name
            //use dot (.) to combile these two variables

            $new_file_name = $jobnumber.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
            //$target_file = $target_dir .$new_file_name;

            /* Add the original filename to our target path.  
              Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
            $target_path = $target_path.$new_file_name; // basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
                echo "The file ".basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']).
                " has been uploaded";
            } else {
                echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
            }
        }

        $query  = "INSERT INTO spotcheckimagepath(imgname,imagepath,spot_check_comment_id)VALUES('".$new_file_name."','".$target_path."','".$reqry2."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    }
?>
```

the ERROR:) Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in

Comment: Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to form tag

Comment: as mentioned earlier, use `multipart/form-data` and also write PHP code on the beginning of document - this is not critical in your case, but this is something like "good practice"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) says you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to you form.

- multipart/form-data

  **No characters are encoded. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control**

So change this line

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="test2.php">
```

to this one

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="test2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also you can see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38029500/trying-to-upload-an-image-but-i-get-errors/38029586#38029586) how check if image was  uploaded

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="test2.php">
```

to

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="test2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Would also check if var exists before trying to access it, can use

`if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']){do something}else{error!}`

Additionally suggest you move your `PHP` code before the html.